# Magento 1.7 - Getting a price rule to trigger with bundle contents

Tags: magento

In our Magento 1.7.0.2 store, we have a bundle product which contains 3 simple products which are checkbox selectable.
So a customer can choose any combination of the individual simple products, 2 products or all 3 and add to cart all from the 1 bundle page.
We want to add a shopping cart price rule which says if all 3 simple products are chosen, then apply a percentage discount. 'Buy all 3 together and save 10%' type of thing.
Seems simple enough, but we can't get the rules to trigger on an SKU match, even if we simply check for the presence of 1 of the simple product SKUs in the cart and even if we chose a 'contains' match which should be less fussy.
Is there a reason that this rule wouldn't work with a bundle? And if there's an issue can anyone recommend a workaround please?
thanks,
James

Answer (score 0):

We sorted this by using a condition for "product type" and "cart price" rules to look for the specific price of all 3 items added.
It's a bit of a fudge, but the end results are the same.